# Using Lookahead and Lookbehind in regex to ignore a word anywhere between a BBCode

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking to expand on a particular code here:

```
/(?<![@#]|(\[img\]))\b(".str_replace(" ", "[\-_ ]", $key).")(?!\[\/img\])\b/i
```

Currently, it detects whether `@` or `#` is directly behind the `$key` in question (which is fine), OR whether `[img]` or `[/img]` is directly before/after the `$key` (a problem). I want to add a wildcard so that the `$key` ANYWHERE in between `[img]` and `[/img]` will not be replaced, while still keeping the fact that `@` or `#` must still be directly behind the `$key`. I am aware that wildcards are not allowed in lookbehind.

Is this possible?

EDIT: I misinterpreted my own code a bit. I realized that `[/img]` will still trigger even if `[img]` doesn't precede the word, thus allowing `@BLUE[/img]` to not trigger. I wish to separate the cases between `#/@` and `[img][/img]`. Assistance on this will greatly help as well.

Basically, everything within `[img]` and `[/img]` will ignore `preg_replace` of the `$key`, `@$key`, and `#$key`. However, even as a standalone `@$key` and `#$key` (without `[img]` tags), `$key` should not be replaced.

Comment: Could you please post a string example and the expected result.

Comment: Assume that `$key` needs to be replaced with GOODBYE for all instances of `$key` (after `str_replace`). Let's assume that `$key` = HELLO. Then following examples hopefully should clarify the confusion:
`[img]SOMETHING HELLO SOMETHING[/img] = [img]SOMETHING HELLO SOMETHING[/img]`, while `HELLO[img]SOMETHING[/img] = GOODBYE[img]SOMETHING[/img]`.

Comment: Ok, it's more clear now, note that this is the kind of things you must systematically put in a question.

Comment: I apologize for my lack of clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using lookarounds is not a good way to do that since you can't use a variable length lookbehind.

The goal is to skip content between `[img]` tags, lets see a way:

```
$result = preg_replace('~\[(img|url)].*?\[/\1](*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(?<![@#])\bHELLO\b~s',
                       'GOODBYE', $str);
```

`(*SKIP)` forbids to retry the part of the string that has been matched on the left if the subpattern fails on the right.

`(*FAIL)` forces the pattern to fail.

Since `[img]` tags are always tried first by the first branch of the pattern, the second branch of the pattern matches always parts of the string that are outside `[img]` tags.

**another way**

you can describe the key you search as a word that is preceded by several `[img]..[/img]` and other characters that are not `[img]` tags or the key word:

```
$pattern = <<<'LOD'
~
(?>                      # atomic group: all possible content before "HELLO"
    (?>                      # other characters
        [^[H]++                  # all characters except [ and H
      |                        # OR
        \[(?!img]|url])          # a [ not followed by img or url
      |                        # OR
        \BH                      # an H not preceded by a word boundary
      |                        # OR
        H(?!ELLO\b)              # an H not followed by ELLO and a word boundary
    )+
  |                        # OR
    \[(img|url)].*?\[/\1]    # img or url tags
)*
\K                       # resets all from the match result
(?<![@#])HELLO
~sx
LOD;
```

Comment: Is it possible to add a OR statement to check for `@/#` separately on top of what you have wrote (by using `(?<![@#])`)? I tried pipeline and it doesn't seem to work. Additionally, I want it to occur for more than one BBCode. How do you implement a several of those? Will `~\[url].*?\[/url](*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\[img].*?\[/img](*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\bHELLO\b~s` suffice?

Comment: @user3245228: see my edit. You can use a capturing group `(url|img)` and a backreference to this group to avoid an other OR statement.